# How to change Json data output in table format

Tags: python, pandas

```
import requests
from pprint import  pprint
import pandas as pd

baseurl = "https://www.nseindia.com/"
url = f'https://www.nseindia.com/api/live-analysis-oi-spurts-underlyings'
headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, '
                         'like Gecko) '
                         'Chrome/80.0.3987.149 Safari/537.36',
           'accept-language': 'en,gu;q=0.9,hi;q=0.8', 'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br'}
session = requests.Session()
request = session.get(baseurl, headers=headers, timeout=30)
cookies = dict(request.cookies)
res = session.get(url, headers=headers, timeout=30, cookies=cookies)

print(res.json())
```

I tried df = pd.DataFrame(res.json()) but couldn't get data in table format. How to do that Plz. Also how to select few particular columns only in data output instead of all columns.

Comment: Instead of the entire code, could you show what the output of your print statement is? Even just the first few lines so we understand the JSON structure.

Comment: What is "table format"?  Can you give an example of expected output?  If you are looking for "pretty print" check https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html

Comment: https://www.nseindia.com/market-data/oi-spurts      Plz open the link and there is a table I want to fetch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
import json
import codecs

df = pd.DataFrame(json.loads(codecs.decode(bytes(res.text, 'utf-8'), 'utf-8-sig'))['data'])
```

And to select a specific columns, you can use :

```
mini_df = df[['symbol', 'latestOI', 'prevOI', 'changeInOI', 'avgInOI']]
```

##### `>>> print(mini_df)`

[image]

Comment: Sir how to select particular columns let's say  'symbol', 'latestOI', 'prevOI', 'changeInOI', 'avgInOI', 'volume','underlying'...... and moreover how to print all 198 rows. I'm using pydroid3 app for Android mobile.

Comment: Sir can you plz update your above answer with this mini_df script Plz. I'm unable to place it correctly .

Comment: Yes I tried print(df) and getting desired data but all rows are not getting printed except first few and last few rows

Comment: Before printing the dataframe, try to run these two lines `pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)` and `pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)`. This will print all the rows and columns of your dataframe.

Comment: Amazing sir, it worked to print all rows. Sir plz update your answer for specific columns

Comment: Ok Brijesh, I updated my answer. Check it out !

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ycM9PeE36QR45z_HHjYG0fbtC_R3RSMw5kgjEtj3IKI/edit?usp=drivesdk    sir I'm unable to reach the destination what I need. Can you help me Plz. Above is my first script of python with the help of internet study and ofcourse you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/73622590/19607727

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/73635566/19607727