# How to use one script output data as input for another script

Tags: python

```
from datetime import timedelta, date
from nsepy import get_history
import requests
import json
import codecs
import pandas as pd

baseurl = "https://www.nseindia.com/"
url = f'https://www.nseindia.com/api/live-analysis-oi-spurts-underlyings'
headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, ''like Gecko) ''Chrome/80.0.3987.149 Safari/537.36','accept-language': 'en,gu;q=0.9,hi;q=0.8', 'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br'}
session = requests.Session()
request = session.get(baseurl, headers=headers, timeout=30)
cookies = dict(request.cookies)
res = session.get(url, headers=headers, timeout=30, cookies=cookies)
df = pd.DataFrame(json.loads(codecs.decode(bytes(res.text, 'utf-8'), 'utf-8-sig'))['data'])
mini_df = df['symbol']
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
#print(df)
#print(mini_df)
print(mini_df.to_string(index=False))
mini_df = []

def importdata(stock):
    stock_fut = get_history(symbol=stock,
           start=date.today() - timedelta(days = 3),           end=date.today(),
           futures=True,
           expiry_date=date(2022,9,29)) 
                              
    print(stock_fut[["Underlying","Change in OI","Open Interest"]])
    
a = []
    
for i in range(0,len(a)):
    print(a[i])
    importdata(a[i])
```

Here I want to make mini_df output value(which is symbols ) to be used as input value of a(script line 32) to get 3 days historical data but getting no output for historical data. How to do that Plz ???

Comment: Save it to a file.

Comment: Just to be clear, your problem is that the final `for` loop does not `print` anything, correct? Your question shows no creating or interacting with a second script to pass data to.

Comment: The relevant code section creates an empty list and then iterates over this empty list. Why do you expect this to create any output to begin with? You are literally telling it to process no data.

Comment: I have created mini_df to get symbol list and further I want to use it as input source for symbol list in next part of script. That's it.

Comment: Please do not edit questions in a way that would invalidate existing answers. This especially includes not swapping the question for another after you already got answers.

Comment: @ MisterMiyagi sorry I'm blocked to ask new question here so I did it. I will keep in mind. How can get my answers plz???

Comment: @BrijeshChaurasia The notice you get when being prevented from asking questions contains [a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th) with instructions. I recommend to follow those.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure, the culprit is here:

```
a = []
    
for i in range(0,len(a)):
    print(a[i])
    importdata(a[i])
```

You iterate over the `range(0,len(a))` but at this moment a is empty. So what should ever happen there? Maybe you have to initialize `a` first? This depends a bit on what you want to achieve there.

Comment: Can you do the same plz

Comment: @BrijeshChaurasia The same what? I'm sorry, but I can't follow.